# How to access files on Dataproc that were passed using --files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
    --cluster=cluster \
    --region=region \
    --files=config.txt \
    --class=class \
    --jars=gs://abc.jar
```

we need to access the config.txt on the driver node.
How can I access the config.txt file on driver node and how to get the path where the config.txt is stored.

In HDFS world with similar --files option I can access the file in driver using java.io.File("config.txt")

Answer (score 0):

I don't have easy access to an gcp account to test (I'm sorry about that), but you could try the `org.apache.spark.SparkFiles.get(String filename)` class method to access the file's absolute path.

Doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html

I hope it helps. See you.

Answer (score 0):

Dataproc sets the current (working) directory of driver process to a tmp dir. Files provided through the `--files` flag will be available in that dir.

For example (list-dir.py):

```py
import os

print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir('.'))
```

then run

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
  --cluster=<cluster> --files=test.json list-dir.py 

...
/tmp/d50faeccc7e94c299cc1e7f257cc542c
['.test.json.crc', '.list-dir.py.crc', 'test.json', 'list-dir.py']
```

You can see `test.json` is in the current dir of the Spark driver process.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this question but this might be helpful to someone:

Since you passed `config.txt` via `--files`, you can access it very easily in your driver node as:

```
with open("config.txt", "r") as f:
    # process f
```

If you want the file to be accessible in every node of your job, you can add it by running `sc.addFile("config.txt")` in your driver node and then access it on any node via `SparkFiles.get("config.txt")`.

HTH